# CSS on Obsidian

Tags: css, obsidian

This topic is about obsidian, I want to change the css of the dataview only on the page called Home, I can change it using the following code but I want to do it only on this page, the path is Personal/Home. Thanks

I'm using cssclass on metadata from Home page

```
.dataview {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [predefined metadata](https://help.obsidian.md/Editing+and+formatting/Metadata), and the cssclass option allows you to style individual notes using CSS snippets.

For example:

```
---
cssclass: home-note
---
```

Try changing your custom CSS as follows:

```
.home-note .dataview {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
}
```

This style the .dataview elements that are inside elements with the home-note class.